# Single particle trajectory in a quadrupole potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

I am wondering if there are any studies of a single (classical) particle trajectory in quadrupole potential:

$$
V(x,y,z)=A\sqrt[]{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{a} + \frac{z^2}{b}} 
$$

Comment: You mean like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_ion_trap)? And where did you get your expression for the quadropole potential? There shouldn't be a square root.

Comment: This potential is a magnetic quadrupole trap, similar to this [link](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&ved=0CH0QFjAL&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciner.com%2FALO%2FS5.doc&ei=nPglUt25Baqj0QXP9YDIAg&usg=AFQjCNGkRVqvCMVySrQHPV5_doMzLtwqvA&sig2=z8qiNke6Z3Od-It8r3zAAQ&bvm=bv.51495398,d.d2k&cad=rja)

Comment: I guess what I like to find out is if this system is an integrable system. If so what are the other constants of motion?